# ECHO on localhost write message twice on windows7

Tags: netty

I'm learning netty from the guide. When use the echo example with echo back , i find something strange. The code just likes sample:

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    //echo back
    System.out.println(buf.readableBytes()); //will print  1
    Channel  ch = e.getChannel();
    ch.write(e.getMessage());
}
```

I use netty 3.6.2 on windows7,with cmd telnet localhost 8080. First time i type char like '1', the telnet console show '1', but form now on when i type any char like '2' , the console show two char like '22'.
What' wrong ?